# Show only Minute scroller of TimePicker in Android

Tags: android, android-widget, android-timepicker

I want to customise the default TimePicker of android.widget. I want to show only the minutes options and hide the Hours and AM/PM options. I was able to hide AM/PM option by using the following code :

```
TimePicker refreshRate= (TimePicker)findViewById(R.id.refreshRate);
refreshRate.setIs24HourView(true);
```

Can anyone tell me how to hide the hours option as I only want to use the Minute option?

Answer (score 4):

The documentation of [TimePicker](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TimePicker.html) does not mention any method or constructor to hide the hour counter. The TimePicker consists basically of two NumberPickers, so for the use of only picking minutes we have to use a [NumberPicker](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/NumberPicker.html) with the following option:

```
minuteNumberPicker.setMinValue(0);
minuteNumberPicker.setMaxValue(59);
```